# Link descarga en HTML

Tags: html

Deseo crear un link de descarga en una página html que descargue una carpeta, pero lo descarga como un archivo .html
La carpeta se llama ghostdance

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Yo me pregunto ¿Alguna vez has descargado tú una carpeta entera de un enlace en una web? Nunca he visto eso. Cuando más, un `zip`, o un `rar` o algún tipo de sincronización con proveedores como `drive` o `OneDrive`, pero ¡Descargar una carpeta de un sitio web! ¡Raro!

Answer (score 1):

no se puede, debes empaquetar lo en zip para descargar la carpeta